# I can not Import my custom modules in Google Colab

Tags: python-3.x, import, module, google-colaboratory

I can not Import  my custom modules in Google Colab,  what is the error in my code

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/gdrive')
%cd /gdrive

import sys
sys.path.append('/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks')

from mylib import MyFunction
MyFunction()

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-06da14aac3e5> in <module>()
----> 1 from mylib import MyFunction
      2 MyFunction()

ImportError: cannot import name 'MyFunction'
```